# How to list all url during tests with watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I am writing a lots of tests (cucumber + watir-webdriver + pageobject) and they take a long time to run.

I am wondering if it is possible to know the list of all pages shown in the browser during tests?
In fact, I want to verify that each test is optimized, and not go through pages of no use. I can watch all the tests to do that, but I think I will be more efficient by just reading the list of urls.

Has someone already made something like that?

Comment: Depending how you wrote/organized your tests, I think the easiest way to track this would be to extend watir-webdriver (goto and link.click) or to add an AfterStep in cucumber. It really depends on how your existing code is written and the type of app being tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you add a log statement to your page objects? I am thinking something like:

```
require 'time'
require 'logger'

module TestHelper
  pagelog = Logger.new('log.txt')

  class LoginPage

      def initialize()
        pagelog.debug "LoginPage: #{Time.now}"
      end

      ...
    end
end
```

Or maybe update PageObjects so it will do it automatically for all PageObject classes.

Comment: I'd rather not have to go that far, but after searching for a few days, I think I have little choice. (I can also add that directly by extending my watir-webdriver class)
Thank you